# BadSqlGrammarException: bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE...] - different behavior on different environments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have server #2 and server #3 and Sprint Boot app jar from 2 different branches.

I compared branches via bitbucket and all configuration classes and pom.xml manually - code is the same (except version for jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.1  vs  jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.2 which should not affect the problem).

I compared property files on both servers – they are the same.

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ ...batch ---
[INFO] ...batch:jar:1.00
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] +- ...:Logging:jar:15.55:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.8.3:test
[INFO] +- ....cib.envkit.pojo:pojo-tester:jar:0.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.meanbean:meanbean:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.intellij:annotations:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- ...:...-Common:jar:15.55:compile
[INFO] |  +- ...:...-Common-API:jar:15.55:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.cyberark.epv.sdk:javapasswordsdk:jar:7.20.110.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:transactions-jta:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.atomikos:transactions-api:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:transactions:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:transactions-jdbc:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:atomikos-util:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.atomikos:transactions-hibernate3:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.jms:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mqjms:jar:7.5.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4:compile
```

The problem happens on server #2 only.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

There is jobRepository configuration:

```
@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager());
    return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

So SpringBoot should use in-memory way.

Output of both apps is the same except the following

Server #2

```
2020-03-03 16:01:21 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:821 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=databaseConfig; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/jpmorgan/ccit/config/DatabaseConfig.class]] 
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]]||
```

> factoryBeanName=databaseConfig

Server #3

```
2020-03-02 17:26:09 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:821 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] 
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=databaseConfig; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/jpmorgan/ccit/config/DatabaseConfig.class]]||
```

> factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration;

So Im thinking the problem can be in bean overriding.

I can’t reproduce this issue on server #3 or local env.

When I copied jar from server #3 to server #2 – it is working fine.

When I copied jar from server #2 to server #3 – got the same problem.

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding property for Spring 2.1? As I know it overriding should be by default in 2.0.

Any other suggestions?

---

Some details:

We are using custom property file, not application.properties.
Runner looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("config.root");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(rootPath + "/batch-log4j.properties");
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource(value = {"file:${config.root}/…-batch.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class BatchConfig {
```

No, I can’t copy jar from local to server.

No, I can’t copy jar from server to local.

---

**UPDATE #1**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:230)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:690)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:732)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:145)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.run(Unknown Source)
        at ....service...BatchService.launchJob(...BatchService.java:68)
        at ....service...BatchService.executeJob(...BatchService.java:101)
        at ....service....BatchService.run(...BatchService.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:698)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
        ... 47 more
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

There is screenshot from successful run on local env with SimpleJobRepository:293. This line from stacktrace above.

[image: SimpleJobRepository:293]

As you can see jobInstanceDao is MapJobInstanceDao.

[MapJobInstanceDao is in-memory implementation of JobInstanceDao](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/MapJobInstanceDao.html)

---

**UPDATE #3**

1. I updated pom.xml and made downgrade jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.2 to jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.1. - the same problem
2. I found the way to copy jar from server #3 to server #2 and run it - jar from server #3 is working fine (with database from server #2)
3. Size of both files are the same
4. I found the way to download both files from the server to local. pom.xml files are the same, spring/springboot/springbatch jars are the same versions

---

**UPDATE #4**

server #3 (success):

```
[org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader] - <Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.jobRepository()>
[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=databaseConfig; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/.../.../config/DatabaseConfig.class]]>
[org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader] - <Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.........config.DatabaseConfig.jobRepository()>
[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'jobRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=databaseConfig; factoryMethodName=jobRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/.../.../config/DatabaseConfig.class]]>
```

server #2 (failure):

```
[org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader] - <Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.........config.DatabaseConfig.jobRepository()>    [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader] - <Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration'>
```

[org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader] - 
    [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] -

So it looks like different order of beans init...

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: The database is the same for all application instance or there are different databases?

Comment: @Andreas see UPDATE #1

Comment: @xcesco yes, different environment - different database. my understanding of MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean in jobRepository() is use in-memory instead of real DB so there is should no be dependency for DB. and my understanding of the problem is in one environment this configuration is not working. am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex You are correct, since that's what the real error tells you: *"Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: **table or view does not exist**"*, which means that table **`BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE`** doesn't exist. --- When looking at an exception, always look at the full stacktrace, mostly the last "Caused by", since that's the real error.

Comment: @Andreas let me simplify my question: why spring is looking for these tables in real DB if i asked him go to in-memory (MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean in jobRepository() )

Comment: Don't know, but if it's not supposed to talk to an actual database, why is the connection to a real database even configured?

Comment: @Andreas because all business data stored in real DB. in-memory for SpringBatch support stuff only. lets skip discussion about architecture, assume this is legacy code and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The exception looks like the table you are using is not corresponding to the Java model defined with JPA/Hibernate. I saw you use Oracle JDBC, so you are using  Oracle databases. I am quite sure that you need to update your database schema. As you probably know, with Spring boot and JPA you can configure JPA behaviour on database schema with the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to verify or create the database schema. Usually, it can set on `application.properties`. In your case put this property in your custom property file.

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Now you can:

1. If your database schema is quite stable, I suggest to you compare your database schemas and update the database schema of the environment that does not work applying the difference respect the one that works.
2. If you are still in the development stage, consider using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`. In this way, your database will be recreated every time the application starts.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. see my update #2. i should not get this exception because i configured in-memory repository for jobRepository.